# With CSS, how do you unhighlight a link after clicking a different link?

Tags: css, hyperlink

For example, on a navigation bar, you only want one link to be hightlighted, the one that the user had most recently clicked. If a user clicks a different link, then the previously highlighted link goes back to normal. How do you do with with CSS?

Comment: Pure CSS won't do it; you'll need some JS.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood correctly, are you talking about normal links in the text, or are you talking about a menu that should have the link for the current page highlighted ?

Comment: a menu that should have the link for the current page highlighted

Comment: @Null I'm not even entirely sure if js would work. The way I imagine it, you'd have to store the link in a cookie, and that's really ridiculous for something this simple.

Comment: @YiJiang As long as you don't change the page, of course. (eg: links target a frame)

Comment: @Yi, of course it would work, you'd read the current URL, find the link whose href attribute matches that and add a class to it.

Comment: @Justin: basically, as @Null also pointed out, you can't do it purely in CSS. You'd need JS, or, in case you're building the page in PHP for example, that could do it as well, without the JS.

Comment: @FreekOne But one URL may have many links pointing to it on the same page. I assume the OP wants the *exact* link that was clicked.

Comment: @Yi, that is indeed possible. I was thinking of a main navigation or something like that, where you wouldn't normally have multiple links pointing to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, what you're asking isn't possible to achieve by using **only** CSS. While there are CSS pseudo-classes for certain link states (such as "a:hover"), there is no CSS selector (at least not in CSS 2.0; maybe 3.0 added something?) that will apply a style on the "current" URL.

To achieve that, you have to combine CSS along with some dynamic means for generating content (such as PHP, CGI, or my favorite - Python). A good guide for doing this in PHP can be found here; you can deduce the general concept from that article and apply it to any content-generation you feel like:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/keepingcurrent/

Isaac